# Trying to fix a two column layout

Tags: html, css, responsive

So I took the following two column layout from W3 schools, which will work for what I'm coding. The code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
      margin: 0;
  }
  /* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
  .column {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  }
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
  }
  /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .column {
          width: 100%;
      }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Responsive Two Column Layout</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect (the columns will stack on top of each other instead of floating next to each other, when the screen is less than 600px wide).</p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And it works for what I need, the only thing is that I need to take the text outside of the columns and have the text blocks centered below each column so that it looks something like this:

[image]

Also, I need the design to have one background image, and a separate image on hover, so that it changes when the cursor goes on top.

Any help will be enormously appreciated.

Comment: ?? is there anything in the columns ? is there an image ? is there an height meant to be set ? Can you clarify ? your code works fine indeed ... if text should be outside, then it should also be outside in html !?!

Comment: Well, the columns will have images, I'm just using this one as an example. Before I start with images I want to take the text outside the columns, but I can't seem to do it without breaking the responsive.

Comment: something like this ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vWOvWb image can be set either in background and living room via padding (fixed value or %/vh/vw/vmin or vmax unit) or image set inside html itself. To draw col of same heigts, you should use display: table&CIE/flex or grid. float, inline-x will not appart putting them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.bigCol {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.column {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px;
}

.row {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .bigCol {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>Responsive Two Column Layout</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect (the columns will stack on top of each other instead of floating next to each other, when the screen is less than 600px wide).</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="bigCol ">
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;"></div>
        <div class="txt"><h2>Column 1</h2><p>Some text..</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bigCol ">
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;"></div>
        <div class="txt"><h2>Column 2</h2><p>Some text..</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```